# Calling setAdapter in Facebook onComplete

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook API and I'm having a hard time getting a `ListView` to show data. My code uses fragments and inflates a layout that has a `ListView` as the root. That `ListView` is wrapped in another `PullToRefreshListView` to enable [Pull To Refresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh). I'm also wrapping the adapter so it can use Mark Murphy's [Endless Adapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless). If I load all the Facebook data before creating the fragment, everything works. But I want to create the fragment with an empty `ListView` and populate it once I get the Facebook data asynchronously.

I'm using the `onComplete(Response response)` callback method in the Facebook `Request`, but it seems that I can't use `setAdapter(adapter)` outside of the `onCreateView()` method for some reason. I feel like I'm just missing something really simple. Here's the code:

```
JSONArray newsFeed;
View view;
ListView feedList;
PullToRefreshListView refreshFeedList;

Request initialFeedRequest = new Request(session, "me/home", null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        Log.i("NewsFeed", "initial load onComplete");
        Log.i("NewsFeed",response.toString());
        responseObject = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
        try {
            newsFeed = responseObject.getJSONArray("data");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        feedAdapter = new FeedAdapter(getActivity(), Space.newsFeed);
        endlessAdapter = new EndlessFeed(feedAdapter);
        feedList.setAdapter(endlessAdapter);
        refreshFeedList.setOnRefreshListener(refreshListener);
        nextPageRequest = response.getRequestForPagedResults(PagingDirection.NEXT);
        String test = feedAdapter.getItem(0).toString();
        Log.i("NewsFeed", "First Item: " + test);
    }
});

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_feed, container, false);
    if(feedAdapter==null){
        Log.i("NewsFeed", "executing Request");
        initialFeedRequest.executeAsync();
    }
    else{
        feedAdapter = new FeedAdapter(getActivity(), Space.newsFeed);
        endlessAdapter = new EndlessFeed(feedAdapter);
        feedList.setAdapter(endlessAdapter);
        refreshFeedList.setOnRefreshListener(refreshListener);
    }
    refreshFeedList = (PullToRefreshListView) view.findViewById(R.id.feedList);
    feedList = refreshFeedList.getRefreshableView();
    feedList.setDividerHeight(0);
}
```

Comment: Is i Your fragment code? What have You observed when call setAdapter from onCompleted()? Just empty list?

Comment: When I call setAdapter from onCompleted() I get an empty list. But if I switch to another fragment and go back to this one, the list populates just fine. I changed what's in the else statement to be identical to the lines after the catch JSONException. So even though the JSONArray is loaded in the onCompleted() it seems like I can't call setAdapter in that same method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is happening because

```
refreshFeedList = (PullToRefreshListView) view.findViewById(R.id.feedList);
feedList = refreshFeedList.getRefreshableView();
feedList.setDividerHeight(0);
```

this code is executed before:

```
feedList.setAdapter(endlessAdapter);
```

in onComplete.
cause u have called `initialFeedRequest.executeAsync();`, that means the request is executed in a different thread beside UI-Thread . u have to execute

```
refreshFeedList = (PullToRefreshListView) view.findViewById(R.id.feedList);
feedList = refreshFeedList.getRefreshableView();
feedList.setDividerHeight(0);
```

after `onComplete` done its job

and another thing, u should return a view from `onViewCreate()` because its return type is `View`

**Edited:**

put your `responseObject` in SharedPreference in `onCopmlete`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("responseObject", responseObject.toString());
editor.commit();
```

getback your `responseObject` in else condition:

```
JSONObject responseObject;
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
String responseObjectString = prefs.getString("responseObject");
if(responseObjectString != null) 
    responseObject = new JSONObject(responseObjectString);
newsFeed = responseObject.getJSONArray("data");

feedAdapter = new FeedAdapter(getActivity(), newsFeed); // use the newsFeed we get from SP
endlessAdapter = new EndlessFeed(feedAdapter);
feedList.setAdapter(endlessAdapter);
refreshFeedList.setOnRefreshListener(refreshListener);
```

if u want to use Application class then see:
[Application class tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/maintaining-global-application-state)

then u have to change your manifest also:

```
<application 
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:name=".Your_Application_class_name">
// other components. ....

</application>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a go when I get home. That makes sense. I think I do return the view, I just didn't copy the entire code for onCreateView().

Comment: It still gives me the same thing with those changes. I have to inflate a ListView before calling setAdapter right?

Comment: The weird thing is that if I navigate to a different fragment and then go back to this one, everything populates fine since the JSONArray is already determined and it's not running the request again. I'm doing all the same code, but running it in the onCompleted doesn't do anything for some reason. Maybe I have to look into forcing the code to run on the main thread just in case it isn't?

Comment: u can try `feedAdapter.notifyDataChange();` in your `else` condition in onCreate.

Comment: what is `Space` class, is this fragment class, or its a `Application` class. if it is fragment class (where u r implementing your above question code) then u have to save the JSONArray somewhere. it could be using sharedpreference. then in your `else` condition retrieve the array, and get the adapter with this array.

Comment: It's an `Application` class. I just recently changed it to save the JSONArray globally, but it was still giving me this same issue when I was using a local JSONArray within the fragment.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I thought about using SharedPreferences, but I wanted to have the global variable be a JSONArray so I can write to and read from it from any fragment or activity. If I do the Facebook request in the splash activity of my app and populate the JSONArray from there, it all works fine so I guess that's my workaround for now. Thanks.