# ListView not visible in ViewPager in custom ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view, viewgroup

I have a custom `ViewGroup` that has a `ViewPager` as a child. This is because I want to add a static header to the `ViewPager` and mess with `onDraw()` to make the header scroll vertically with the `ViewPager` content. My `ViewPager` has a `ListView` as a child. I'm able to create the `ListView` and the adapter and even set the adapter to the `ListView`. When I read `wallList.getAdapter().getItemAt(0).toString()` it returns the data I would expect it to return. But for some reason, I can't see the `ListView` at all.

The `ViewPager` still works as intended and the other four pages have arbitrary text for the time being. But the center page which is supposed to contain the `ListView` shows a blank screen. I can't figure out what's going on, but it sounds similar to a problem I had before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993439/calling-setadapter-in-facebook-oncomplete) and was able to hack my way to get something acceptable, but wasn't able to answer my original question.

It seems like you can only call `setAdapter()` in certain places, not only does it have to be on the UI thread (I think) but it seems to have trouble doing it within certain methods, custom or overrided. Here's my custom ViewGroup code.

```
public class CustomProfilePager extends ViewGroup{

Bitmap coverPhoto, profilePhoto;
Paint coverStyle, profileStyle;
String name;
int coverHeight;
ViewPager pager;
ProfilePagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
ListView wallList;
Context context;

public CustomProfilePager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    Log.i("CustomPager", "calling onLayout()");
    pager.layout(0, coverHeight+240, getWidth(), getHeight());
//      for(int i=0; i<getChildCount(); i++){
//          getChildAt(i).layout(l, t, r, b);
//      }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Log.i("CustomPager", "calling onDraw()");
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if(coverPhoto!=null){
        canvas.drawBitmap(coverPhoto, 0, 0, coverStyle);
    }
}

public void init(String name){
    Log.i("CustomPager", "calling init()");
    this.name = name;
    coverStyle = new Paint();
    coverHeight = (int) (getWidth()/2.7);
    profileStyle = new Paint();
    wallList = new ListView(context);
    pagerAdapter = new ProfilePagerAdapter();
    pager = new ViewPager(context);
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    addView(pager);
    pager.setCurrentItem(2);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
}

public void setCoverPhoto(Bitmap bitmap){
    Log.i("CustomPager", "calling setCoverPhoto()");
    int initialWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    int initialHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    int finalHeight = (int) (initialWidth/2.7);
    int initialYoffset = (int) (initialHeight-finalHeight)/2;
    this.coverPhoto = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, initialYoffset, bitmap.getWidth(), finalHeight);
    invalidate();
}

public void setProfilePhoto(Bitmap bitmap){
    this.profilePhoto = bitmap;
}

public ViewPager getViewPager(){
    return pager;
}

public void setWallAdapter(Profile.WallAdapter adapter){
    Log.i("CustomPager", "calling setWallAdapter()");
    wallList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public class ProfilePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        ViewPager parent = (ViewPager) collection;
        switch (position) {
        case 2: // Wall
            wallList.setDividerHeight(0);
            parent.addView(wallList);
            return wallList;
        default:
            TextView testText = new TextView(context);
            testText.setText(String.valueOf(position) + ": " + name);
            testText.setTextSize(46);
            testText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            parent.addView(testText);
            return testText;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you used `hierarchyviewer` to see where is your `ListView` in the layout?

Comment: While I was looking at it with heirarchyviewer, I got a text from the wife. I did a quick reply (using CM10.1) and after I dismissed the text message window that came up, I could see the `ListView` but only in the area where the text message window was. So I think it's there, but it's covered up by something.

Comment: hierarchyviewer says the `ListView` takes 0.000 ms to measure and layout, but .153 ms to draw. I think that means it isn't measuring it but I get a NPE when I call `measureChild()` in the `onMeasure()` method.

Comment: What method are you using(I'm referring to `getItemAt()` is that your real code)? Also are you sure your cover photo isn't covering the `ListView? Did you tried without the cover photo?

Comment: I wasn't bothering with `getItemAt()`. Instead I was just using the `wallList` object since I don't know the index of it anyway. Also, I just commented out the stuff in `setCoverPhoto()` and that wasn't the issue.

Comment: I changed it from sublassing `ViewGroup` to subclassing `FrameLayout` and everything seems to work fine now....thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't really obvious and I'm not sure exactly what caused it in the first place. All I had to do was sublass `FrameLayout` instead of `ViewGroup` and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I too have experience that, Some of the View in my ViewPager were getting lost. When debug came to know that it contain only 2 (some time even 1) views in ViewPager. But actually there has to be 3 views since i implemented circular viewpager.

After many trial and error method, i commented the removeView line from destoryItem and i was surprise and it was working perfectly.

I am not sure will this solved your problem since the documentation for destroyItem says

> Remove a page for the given position. The adapter is responsible for
>   removing the view from its container, although it only must ensure
>   this is done by the time it returns from finishUpdate(ViewGroup).

For me, there should always be 3 views in my ViewPager. since it was a circular ViewPager.

```
public class ProfilePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {

    }
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup collection, int position) {
        ViewPager parent = (ViewPager) collection;
        switch (position) {
        case 2: // Wall
            wallList.setDividerHeight(0);
            parent.addView(wallList);
            return wallList;
        default:
            TextView testText = new TextView(context);
            testText.setText(String.valueOf(position) + ": " + name);
            testText.setTextSize(46);
            testText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            parent.addView(testText);
            return testText;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out and see if it works but I suspect it won't solve the problem. I want 5 pages and I get 5 pages that all work as intended except for the one page with the `ListView` that shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that you may only really need to call

```
notifyDataSetChanged()
```

on the PagerAdapter and the ListView will then be displayed properly.

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty sure I tried that, but I'll give it another go just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you called setWillNotDrawEnabled(false) on your customViewGroup?

By default ViewGroups dont call the onDraw method, also try implmenting the onDispatchDraw instead of the onDraw method

[Android Custom Layout - onDraw() never gets called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056331/android-custom-layout-ondraw-never-gets-called)